# How to override Mass action in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, massaction, virtualtype

How to override Mass action in Magento module.

I want to override below files.

**Vendorname\ModuleName\Ui\Component\MassAction\Status to my custom module.**

Comment: Please share the code of this class?

Comment: Please find below files, that i want to override
https://github.com/iovistaworld/iovista/blob/main/Options.php

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the Options class, you can use preference for that class.

Add below code in Vendorname/ModuleName/etc/di.xml of custom module :

```
<preference for="OriginalVendor\OriginalModule\Ui\Component\MassAction\Status" type="Vendorname\ModuleName\Ui\Component\MassAction\Status" />
```

Then, Create a new file in your custom module at the following location: Vendorname/ModuleName/Ui/Component/MassAction/Status.php.

In this file, declare your class and extend the original mass action file that you want to override. For example:

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\ModuleName\Ui\Component\MassAction;

use OriginalVendor\OriginalModule\Ui\Component\MassAction\Status as OriginalStatus;

class Status extends OriginalStatus
{
    // Your custom code here
}
```

But if you want to modify the return value of jsonSerialize function, best way is to write after plugin for that method.

Define plugin in di.xml

```
 <type name="Vendorname\ModuleName\Ui\Component\MassAction\Status\Options">
     <plugin name="Custom_Module::modifyOptions" type="Custom\Module\Plugin\OptionsPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
 </type>
```

File - OptionsPlugin.php

```
namespace Custom\Module\Plugin;

class OptionsPlugin
{
    public function afterGetOptions(\Vendorname\ModuleName\Ui\Component\MassAction\Status\Options $options, $result)
    {
        // modify the $result array here
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I want edit this file and want to add single line above the public function jsonSerialize() file.
Vendorname\ModuleName\Ui\Component\MassAction\Status\Options.php
So what methods should I use?